# Validate user input for social security number in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation

I want to validate the format of a social security number when initializing an object or using a setter to change the value of that object after its been made. Obviously this will be done via an if statement and a regex string but I do not know how to make that happen in Java.

I found this expression on a different site:

```
Regex : ^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
```

However i cannot tell if its accurate or not, nor do I understand the syntax to check user input against this.

```
setSocNum(String x){

if (![regex here]){
System.out.println("please enter a valid social security number")
}
}
```

I am unable to tell how to check against a regex string. If Someone can help me with the syntax here I could easily adapt it to other parts of the class I am working on. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you should start with a finding of some information about how these numbers should look and what is considered as a valid number.

Comment: Do you have an example. From which country is the social security number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class from java and use its `matches` method which takes two arguments, first one being the regex that you have mentioned and second argument a string and it returns a `boolean` value which will tell whether the string matched with the regex or not. Here is a sample code for same,

```
String input = "somedata";
Pattern.matches("^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$", input);
```

Your method should look something like this,

```
public void setSocNum(String x) {

    if (Pattern.matches("^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$", x)) {
        System.out.println("please enter a valid social security number");
    }
    // further logic goes here
}
```

Creation of `Pattern` object is heavy, so if you intend to use the code where it gets called many times, you should create it once and re-use and avoid re-creation of it again and again.

**Here is the explanation of regex:**

```
^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?!000|666)` - This negative look ahead means, fail the match if the string starts with `000` or `666`
- `[0-8]` - Then match and consume the next digit if it is in range `0` to `8`
- `[0-9]{2}` - Then match and consume the next any two digits where [0-9] means any digit which you can also compactly write as `\d`
- `-` - Then followed by a hyphen
- `(?!00)` - This negative look ahead rejects the match if the next two digits are `00`
- `[0-9]{2}` - Then next it matches and consumes any two digits
- `-` - Then again followed by a hyphen
- `(?!0000)` - This negative look ahead rejects the match if the next four digits are `0000`
- `[0-9]{4}` - Then next it matches and consumes any four digits
- `$` - End of string

Hope my explanation is clear. Let me know for any queries.

Here is the code I suggested in my comment,

```
public static Pattern SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUM_PAT = Pattern.compile("^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$");

public static boolean isValidSocialSecurityNumber(String input) {
    return SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUM_PAT.matcher(input).matches();
}
```

You can place this code in some class like `SocialSecurityUtils.java` and call it from wherever you want using `SocialSecurityUtils.isValidSocialSecurityNumber("socialsecuritynumber")`

Comment: One helpful site to test inputs versus regex is https://regex101.com/ for example, see here for your pattern being tested: https://regex101.com/r/fUFZm6/1

Comment: OK, so you need to store the pattern in a variable then just check for matches against the variable?

Comment: @DanMan3395: Yes, you should preferably create the Pattern object as `static final` so you don't have to create it again and again. I would recommend creating a method which takes your input and just returns the `boolean` value telling whether your input is a valid social security number or not. Let me add the code that I am suggesting in my answer.

Comment: oh i see what you mean. Instead of checking by creating the pattern every time I initialize and object I should use a checker method and just run that against each object as its made. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Pattern` to match the string with regex.

```
    private static Pattern socSecPattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$");

    private void setSocNum(String x){
        if (!socSecPattern.matcher(x).matches()){
            System.out.println("please enter a valid social security number")
        }
    }
```

It is a good idea to have the `Pattern` variable as be static since it will be called many times.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the meaning of this pattern: `^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$`

- `(?!000|666)`: Look ahead in the provided string and ensures that it does not have `000` or `666`. If you find those patterns, then fail the match - return invalid input.
- `[0-8][0-9]{2}-`: Expects three digits followed by a `-` where the first one is from a range of 0 to 8, and the other two are from a range of 0 to 9
- `(?!0000)` Similar to the first one, look ahead and make sure that this pattern `0000` does not exist otherwise fail the validation
- `[0-9]{4}`: Expects four digits from a range of 0 to 9

As for `^` and `$`, they match the beginning and the end of the string respectively.

Hope that helps.